# How to bulk create AdWords campaigns, ad groups, ads and keywords using a single CSV?

Tags: google-ads

I have tried to create campaigns, ad groups, ads and keywords by flattening a hierarchical structure into a flat CSV.

However, when I try to upload the file using "Bulk uploads" feature, I am getting an error:

> Unable to determine the entity-type of this row. Make sure to only provide fields for columns that are appropriate for the entity.

Does this mean that I need to upload campaigns, ad groups, ads and keywords in separate steps?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: @closetnoc I mention the relevant tags and operations. What information is missing?

Comment: Ooopppsss! My bad! Cheers!!

Comment: It would be best to mention this in the question.

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question, the trick is to leave the irrelevant fields empty, e.g. This document describes one campaign and one ad group.

```
Bid Strategy Type,Budget,Campaign state,Campaign subtype,Campaign type,Campaign,Ad group state,Ad group,Default max. CPC
cpc,1000000,enabled,Standard,Search Only,Poster Boys (2017),,,
,,,,,Poster Boys (2017),enabled,Poster Boys (2017),200000
```

Notice that the ad group describing row excludes campaign specific field values.

Refer to https://support.google.com/adwords/editor/answer/56368 for additional documentation on bulk uploads.

Bonus:

Somewhat off-topic, but it wasted me good 30 minutes.

When using this approach and using "Upload and preview" to test, you will get multiple errors such as "Item not found" and "Could not find the specified Ad Group". Ignore these errors and proceed to commit the changes. The errors are a red herring.

Comment: +1, saved me a lot of time. Also, AdWords Scripts has some documentation about the fields, grouped by type, which is broadly applicable to the csv import via GUI as well: https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/features/bulk-upload-entities